# How to get the list of changed files since the creation of a branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose I create a branch `dev` and then made 5 commits and total files changed were 5.

Is there any command that I can run to see only the list of files changed since the branch was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Branches don't retain "creation" information, so you cannot get git to do this completely automatically and generally.  However, if you know there are 5 "interesting" commits:

```
         A <- B <- C <- D <- E   <- dev
        /
... <- * <- o <- ...  <-- master
```

and you want to compare commit `E`, the tip of branch `dev`, to commit `*`, the commit before commit `A`:

```
$ git diff dev~5 dev
```

will show you a complete diff of the two.  The `~5` notation means "count back five parents": start at `E`, step back one to `D`, step back one to `C`, etc.; if you do this five times you land on the commit marked `*`.

The diff shows you the difference between these two commits.  By default, it shows you everything, but if you want to see the names of files changed (or added or deleted, etc.), you can add `--name-only`.

---

Typically a better way to do this is not to care when branch `dev` was *created*, but only where `dev` and some other branch (such as `master`) *join up*.  In this case, for instance, you might want to locate commit `*` by asking: "Where do `master` and `dev` first join up in history, starting from the tips of `dev` and `master` and working backwards?"

To find this, you can ask git for the "merge base" of the two branches:

```
$ git merge-base dev master
```

This will produce the raw commit-ID of the merge-base (commit `*` in the drawing).  You can then feed this to `git diff` (with `--name-only`, `--name-status`, `--stat`, or whatever you like):

```
$ git diff --name-status $(git merge-base dev master) dev
```

This is common enough to want, that `git diff` re-uses the special `master...dev` syntax (see [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for details):

```
$ git diff --name-status master...dev
```

The three-dot syntax here tells `git diff` to find the merge-base, and produce the diff between that and the commit identified on the right: the tip of branch `dev`.